# Connection string for Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus.ServiceBusClient

Tags: azure, connection-string, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues

I'm trying to get started with Azure ServiceBus, but the Gods of Documentation are against me. I'm following [this MS article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-dotnet-get-started-with-queues), which says this code will allow me to send a message...

```
public class Program 
{
    static string connectionString = "<NAMESPACE CONNECTION STRING>";
    
    static string queueName = "<QUEUE NAME>";

    static async Task Main(string[] args) 
    {
        await SendMessageAsync();
    }

    static async Task SendMessageAsync() 
    {
        // create a Service Bus client 
        ServiceBusClient client = new ServiceBusClient(connectionString);

        // create a sender for the queue 
        ServiceBusSender sender = client.CreateSender(queueName);

        // create a message that we can send
        ServiceBusMessage message = new ServiceBusMessage("Hello world!");

        // send the message
        await sender.SendMessageAsync(message);
        
        Console.WriteLine($"Sent a single message to the queue: {queueName}");
    }
}
```

---

I assigned values to the 2 constants, the connection string from the portal and the name of the queue, but when I compile and run it it fails on the line to instantiate the `ServiceBusClient`...

> System.ArgumentException
> HResult=0x80070057
> Message=The connection string used for an Service Bus client must specify the Service Bus namespace host and either a Shared Access Key (both the name and value) OR a Shared Access Signature to be valid. (Parameter 'connectionString')
> Source=Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus

More digging and I discover the phrase "FullyQualifiedNamespace" being used for the connection string, so I replaced the value I had with `MyServiceBusName.queue.core.windows.net` and run that. The results are different but not good...

> System.FormatException
> HResult=0x80131537
> Message=The connection string could not be parsed; either it was malformed or contains no well-known tokens.
> Source=Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus

I'm guessing that from the first attempt that there is a way of getting the SAS Token or Shared Access Key in as part of the connection string, I just can't work out how.

I've tried just tacking on the Shared Access Key (SAK)

```
static string connectionString = 
   "MyServiceBusName.queue.core.windows.net;AccountKey=accountKeyValue
```

No joy, same if I don't include the "name" element of the SAK.

likewise I've tried adding the SAS Token that the portal gave me, again with no joy.

Can *someone* please tell me what I'm not doing that I should be, please

**UPDATE:**

More digging suggests that making the following change should *also* work...

```
ServiceBusClient client = 
    new ServiceBusClient(connectionString, new DefaultCredentials())
```

---

With my connection string just set to `MyServiceBusName.queue.core.windows.net` and the modified constructor, it gets instantiates `ServiceBusClient` OK, but then just hangs and, ultimately, times out when trying to actually send a message.

The queue appears to be working OK as I can add messages in the portal and see them in the instance of Storage Explorer that I'm using on my machine. Likewise I can create message in Storage Explorer and see them in the Portal.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is how the connection string should be specified for a Service Bus Namespace:

```
Endpoint=sb://namespacename.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=RootManageSharedAccessKey;SharedAccessKey=yZOy10HAJTNkyaKOqwjSricOEud7QLK7R62KyVfjCt4=
```

You can get this information from Azure Portal by going into `Shared Access Policy` > `RootManageSharedAccessKey` > `Primary (or Secondary) Connection String` for your Service Bus Namespace.

**UPDATE**

It seems you're trying to use Storage Queues which are part of Azure Storage. If that is the case, then your connection string would be:

```
DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=accountname;AccountKey=xxxx==;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net;
```

Please note that you cannot use `Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus` package to manage your Storage Queues. You will need to use `Azure.Storage.Queues` package.

Comment: Sadly not. I suspect that is true if you are using `Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus` but I'm trying to use the newer `Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus`

Using your offered solution results in 

    Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus.ServiceBusException: 'No such host is known. 
    ErrorCode: HostNotFound (ServiceCommunicationProblem)'

Comment: It seems you're using Storage Queues (based on your edit about being able to use Storage Explorer to send messages). Please see my updated answer.

Comment: I am *so* dumb!

Comment: I use the endpoint to do moq testing, and it passed....